# How to pass the results from a HTMLDropDownList to a MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with a HTML.DropDownList. I am trying to figure out how to capture the selection. The selection contains two values and only one value can be selected. The value is a room number that will be a string input to my Switch in the controller.

I've got the dropdownlist working, I've got the model working and sending data to the view. I can't figure out how to pass through the value of the DropDownList.

I know I need some Jquery to trigger the POST to the controller, not sure what to write though. Any help is appreciated. Code is below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectRoomNumber", "PEO"))
{
    <fieldset>
        Room Numbers
        @Html.DropDownList("RoomList", (SelectList) ViewBag.RoomList)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
```

I am calling the method SelectRoomNumber in the PEO controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SelectRoomNumber()
        {

            string roomNumber ="";
            string readValueBv = "T";
            string readValueAv = "80";
            string readValueMv = "Occ";

            switch (roomNumber)
            {
                case ("1B^1001^01"):
                    model.RmNum = "1B^1001^01";
                    model.BvInstance = 3000018;
                    model.AvInstance = 3000022;
                    model.MvInstance = 3000040;
                    break;

                case ("1B^1002^01"):
                    model.RmNum = "1B^1002^01";
                    model.BvInstance = 3000020;
                    model.AvInstance = 3000023;
                    model.MvInstance = 3000042;
                    break;

                default:
                    model.RmNum = "Room";
                    model.BvInstance = 0;
                    model.AvInstance= 0;
                    model.MvInstance= 0;
                    break;
            }

            //Start BACnet Message Que
            _bacnetAgent.StartActivity(IpAddress);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //Trigger Read Method BV
            _bacnetAgent.Read(deviceId, BvReadBacObj, model.BvInstance, BacProp, out readValueBv);
            model.BvRes = readValueBv;

            //Trigger Read Method AV
            _bacnetAgent.Read(deviceId, AvReadBacObj, model.AvInstance, BacProp, out readValueAv);
            model.AvRes = readValueAv;

            //Trigger Read Method MV
            _bacnetAgent.Read(deviceId, MvReadBacObj, model.MvInstance, BacProp, out readValueMv);
            model.MvRes = readValueMv;

            return View("PEO", model);

        }
```

Comment: Start with a view model containing 2 properties - `public int RoomNumber { get; set; }` and `public SelectList RoomList { get; set; }`. Initialize an instance of the class in your GET method, populate the `SelectList` and pass the instance  to the view. In the view use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoomNumber, Model.RoomList)` and post back your model. The POST method should be `public ActionResult SelectRoomNumber(yourModelType model)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add this if you want it as integer:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectRoomNumber(int RoomList)
{

}
```

Otherwise as a string :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectRoomNumber(string RoomList)
{

}
```

`RoomList` is the keyname which you have entered in your view:

```
@Html.DropdownList("KEYNAME")
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been switching over from PHP MVC to ASP.Net MVC figured it was something easy. Still learning :-)

Answer (score 1):

just create a variable with the same name of the attribute name of your select element.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectRoomNumber(string RoomList)
{
//rest of your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC view works hand in hand with the **associated controller**, so u can pass a value or values from the view to the controller as long as the id in the view and in the controller  are the **same names**. e.g 
in your controller u have this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectRoomNumber(string RoomList)
{
}
```

and in your view u should have this

```
Html.Textbox("RoomList")
```